# MySql: get parent, child and grandchild with DESC ordering

Tags: mysql

table name `tbl_product_category`

```
id  parent_id   name    ordering

1   0   Air Conditioner 1
2   0   Commercial AC   2
3   1   Refrigeration   3
4   2   Air Cooler  4
5   2   Water Dispenser 5
6   1   Rice Cooker 6
7   4   Imduction Oven  7
8   6   Fan 8
```

Here is my mysql query and i'm trying to add `ORDER BY ordering DESC, level`

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS men.*,
            (
                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub3.ordering, sub3.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub4.ordering, sub4.ordering), 10, '0'), '#lv5')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub3 ON (sub2.id = sub3.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub4 ON (sub3.id = sub4.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub4.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub3.ordering, sub3.ordering), 10, '0'), '#lv4')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub3 ON (sub2.id = sub3.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub3.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '#lv3')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub2.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '#lv2')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub1.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '#lv1')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent
                WHERE parent.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

            ) AS level

        FROM `tbl_product_category` men
        ORDER BY level
```

result with `ORDER BY level`

```
level (new field)
0000000011#lv1
0000000011.0000000044#lv2
0000000011.0000000044.0000000077#lv3
0000000011.0000000055#lv2
0000000088#lv1
0000001111#lv1
0000001111.0000000033#lv2
0000001111.0000000066#lv2
```

result with `ORDER BY ordering DESC, level`

```
level (new field)
0000001111#lv1
0000000088#lv1
0000000011.0000000044.0000000077#lv3
0000001111.0000000066#lv2
0000000011.0000000055#lv2
0000000011.0000000044#lv2
0000001111.0000000033#lv2
0000000011#lv1
```

### Here is what i hope:

```
level (new field)
0000001111#lv1
0000001111.0000000066#lv2
0000001111.0000000033#lv2
0000000088#lv1
0000000011#lv1
0000000011.0000000055#lv2
0000000011.0000000044#lv2
0000000011.0000000044.0000000077#lv3
```

Comment: can you explain this: `CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering)` ? don't understand the purpose

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ `CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '#lv1')` to concat ordering field value eg: `Air Conditioner`  ordering value `1` result `0000000011#lv1`

Comment: `order by level DESC` ?

Comment: @SmithFoto yeah see that, but, why do you double the ordering field value?

Comment: @pala_ result `
0000000022.0000000044#lv2

0000000022#lv1` so i want `#lv1` on the top of `#lv2`

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ this not importance. please help me ordering the result

Comment: instead of finishing with #lv1, #lv2 etc - what about padding them with additional .00000000 groups?, or even returning what you have now, with an additional field that is padded out with .0000000 groups, and sorting on the additional field

Comment: actually it will need to be .9999999999, see my example below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to include an additional field just for sorting. This should work:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS men.*,
            (
                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub3.ordering, sub3.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub4.ordering, sub4.ordering), 10, '0'), '#lv5')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub3 ON (sub2.id = sub3.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub4 ON (sub3.id = sub4.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub4.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub3.ordering, sub3.ordering), 10, '0'), '#lv4')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub3 ON (sub2.id = sub3.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub3.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '#lv3')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub2.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '#lv2')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub1.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '#lv1')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent
                WHERE parent.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

            ) AS level,
              (
                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub3.ordering, sub3.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub4.ordering, sub4.ordering), 10, '0'), '')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub3 ON (sub2.id = sub3.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub4 ON (sub3.id = sub4.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub4.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub3.ordering, sub3.ordering), 10, '0'), '.9999999999')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub3 ON (sub2.id = sub3.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub3.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub2.ordering, sub2.ordering), 10, '0'), '.9999999999.9999999999')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub2 ON (sub1.id = sub2.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub2.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.', LPAD( CONCAT(sub1.ordering, sub1.ordering), 10, '0'), '.9999999999.9999999999.9999999999')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent 
                INNER JOIN `tbl_product_category` sub1 ON (parent.id = sub1.parent_id) 
                WHERE sub1.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0

                UNION

                SELECT CONCAT( LPAD( CONCAT(parent.ordering, parent.ordering), 10, '0') , '.9999999999.9999999999.9999999999.9999999999')
                FROM `tbl_product_category` parent
                WHERE parent.id = men.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

            ) AS sorting


        FROM `tbl_product_category` men
        ORDER BY sorting desc
```

And here is an example fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be613/3

Comment: thank you. i use `00000000` it work. have a nice day